# How to check nod exist in html page?

Tags: html-agility-pack

i have html page and parsing with htmlagilitypack
i manualy change how value for node exist but i need automatic change by value 'statusAct' or 'statusInac'

```
                   if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode text in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='rTbl']/tr/td/span[@class='statusAct']/a[@title='Status Definitions']/text()"))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = text.InnerText;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode text in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='rTbl']/tr/td/span[@class='statusInac']/a[@title='Status Definitions']/text()"))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = text.InnerText;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code above? you have a sample input? whats the error you are getting now?

Comment: Also, what role does `i` play in your script ?